Problema para importar mariadb en un código
Tengo un problema para poder importar mariadb en un código incluso con el paquete ya instalado en Python.
Tengo el código así:
from tkinter import *
import mariadb
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from registros import Registros

Pero me muestra este error :

Import "mariadb" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports

Cuando reviso los paquetes instalados en pip me aparece que maria esta incluido:
$ pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
mariadb                1.1.10
mysql-connector-python 8.4.0
packaging              24.0
python-decouple        3.8
python-dotenv          1.0.1
setuptools             69.5.1
wheel                  0.43.0


Eso , de primeras, no es un error como tal, es solo un aviso del linter de VSC. ¿Si ejecutas el script te lanza un ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mariadb' el intérprete? Si lo hace entonces has instalado el paquete en el intéprete/venv equivocado, no tienes el VENV correcto activado, estás usando el que no debes en VSC o simplemente se instaló incorrectamente. En cambio, si no lanza esa excepción, entonces no hay ningún problema con la instalación, es solo un problema del linter o de configuración de VSC.
